# Get a variable after exiting a while loop

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

I'm working on a validation system, there are several msgs in my DB with value = 0 (it means they are not accepted yet) so I created a page to change the value to 1 if the validation checkbox is checked.

Here the code:

```
<?php   
        if (isset($_POST['valider']))           
            {                   
                $reponse1 = db_query('UPDATE messages SET value = 1 WHERE id = ?', array($donneesmsg['id']));
                echo "NSF validée";                 
            }       
        if (isset($_POST['delete']))            
            {                   
                $reponse1 = db_query('DELETE FROM messages WHERE id = ?', array($donneesmsg['id']));                    
                echo "NSF supprimée";                   
            }

$reponse = db_query('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE value = 0');
while ($donneesmsg = $reponse->fetch()) {

?>

<h5><?php echo $donneesmsg['Pseudo']; ?></h5>

<p class="text-center text-align"><?php echo $donneesmsg['Message']; ?></p>

<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="index.php?page=changeto1">

            <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="valider" value="1">
            Valider
            </label>


            <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete">
            Supprimer
            </label>

            <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $donneesmsg['id']; ?>">




<?php

}

?>

<br>
<br>

<button type="submit" class="btn">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

But I have a problem, the variable $donneesmsg['id'] doesn't exist anymore when the page is submitted because the variable was definied first in a while loop.

Unfortunately, I really need this ID to get my system working. 
How can I get this ID?

Comment: What have you tried? Think, your variable is right there, you can do anything with it inside the loop, **including** saving it on an auxiliary array outside of the loop for later use.

Answer (score 0):

You have the loop in the wrong place. With the loop the way you have it, it will have an opening form tag for every checkbox.  Also a good way to get multiple different checkboxes is to set it up as an array. To do those it would look like this:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="index.php?page=changeto1">    

    <?php 
        $reponse = db_query('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE value = 0');
        while ($donneesmsg = $reponse->fetch()) :
    ?>

        <h5><?php echo $donneesmsg['Pseudo']; ?></h5>

        <p class="text-center text-align"><?php echo $donneesmsg['Message']; ?></p>

        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="valider[<?php echo $donneesmsg['id']; ?>]" value="1">
            Valider
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete[<?php echo $donneesmsg['id']; ?>]">
            Supprimer
        </label>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <br>
    <br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

And then on your page where the form is submitted you can do:

```
<?php

    $idsToValidate = array_keys($_POST['valider']);
    $idsToDelete   = array_keys($_POST['delete']);
```

Also if you want instead of doing `<input name="delete[*id*]" value="1" />` you could do `<input name="delete[]" value="*id*" />` and then you wouldn't need to do array_keys on the result it would already be an array of the ids you want to work with

Answer (score 0):

Is it how i should set it up ?

```
<?php

$idsToValidate = array_keys($_POST['valider']);
$idsToDelete   = array_keys($_POST['delete']);

        if (isset($idsToValidate))

            {

                $reponse1 = db_query('UPDATE messages SET value = 1 WHERE id = ?', array($idsToValidate['id']));

                echo "<center>NSF validée</center>";

            }



        if (isset($idsToDelete))

            {

                $reponse1 = db_query('DELETE FROM messages WHERE id = ?', array($idsToDelete['id']));

                echo "<center>NSF supprimée</center>";

            }

?>


<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="index.php?page=changeto1">    

    <?php 
        $reponse = db_query('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE value = 0');
        while ($donneesmsg = $reponse->fetch()) :
    ?>

        <h5><?php echo $donneesmsg['Pseudo']; ?></h5>

        <p class="text-center text-align"><?php echo $donneesmsg['Message']; ?></p>

        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="valider[<?php echo $donneesmsg['id']; ?>]" value="1">
            Valider
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete[<?php echo $donneesmsg['id']; ?>]">
            Supprimer
        </label>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <br>
    <br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```